# Trying to click ClickFunnels button through Hubspot onFormSubmit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hubspot

I'm trying to submit a Hubspot form embed on my Clickfunnels page and have it click a clickfunnels form submit button element on the page via the onFormSubmit function.
I'm doing it this way for conversion tracking purposes in clickfunnels. My console log is showing the button element as null. Its not working out, any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "0000000",
    formId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    onFormSubmit: function($form) {   
        var hiddenButton = document.getElementById("#tmp_button-44284");                   
        console.log('Got element: ' + hiddenButton);
        $(hiddenButton).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the `#` from `.getElementById()`.

Comment: Or change `document.getElementById` to `$`